# My accepted answer getting downvoted because of a better one - could we delete mine?

Tags: support, status-completed, downvotes, accepted-answer

In the question [User specific hosts in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17565657/1983854) I added a comment with what I thought that could be a solution. As it seemed to solve the issue, I made it [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17565916/1983854) that got accepted by the OP.

After a while, another user (dogbane) added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17566567/1983854) that is way better than mine, also using the right tool for it.

I didn't notice the existence of this new answer until I started to get downvoted, so that I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565657/user-specific-hosts-in-linux#comment34632108_17565657) to the OP:

> I would suggest you to accept @dogbane 's answer, as it is way better
> and this way I can delete mine. Now I am getting some downvotes and I
> understand them :)

The OP did not change the accepted answer. I don't blame him for it, it's his right to do so.

I would like to know if it is possible for the community to just delete my answer and make the other answer the accepted one.

---

### Update

I flagged it and got deleted. Many thanks, moderators!

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: You can ask mods to disassociate that answer from your account by a flag. Refer [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144114/245167) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149413/245167)

Comment: I didn't know "an answer isn't as good as other answers" was an acceptable reason to downvote.  Is that a thing now?

Comment: @Chance that is very true. I was also surprised, but I guess the point of the answer being accepted made people feel the need to downvote, supposedly to make sure the other one would go up and up...

Comment: That's total crap.  There is one answer accepted by the user, but other answers can be helpful to the person asking and for others.  The only time I would do so is if the answer was posted after the original and was along the same vein (even then I usually won't though), or the answer just really isn't helpful.  I haven't actually seen your answer though, so maybe I'm inferring too much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do three things here :-

1. Comment on OP's post to change the accepted answer - *You already did that*
2. Instead of requesting for a deletion, edit your post and make it better if you cannot, refer next point
3. Edit your post and specify that [*Please refer dogbane(username) answer which is better than mine*]

If you think it is really bad answer or it doesn't serve a purpose as a secondary solution, flag a moderator for deletion

Comment: Thanks! Well it is not thaaat bad answer, only that the other one is the right tool for it. I guess I am getting downvoted by people that wants to make clear it is the other answer the one that just be on top.

Comment: @fedorqui yea so thats good that people are actually deciding which answer is a better one, eventually your posts score will drop down and the other answer will come to action as I assume that when they down vote yours, they up vote the other answer at the same time

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this answer and combine it with [the comment by Infinite Recursion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266351/my-accepted-answer-getting-downvoted-because-of-a-better-one-could-we-delete-m#comment65162_266351). If he happens to make it an answer and you get downvoted, don't worry, I will accept his :P

Comment: How about turning the answer into a _community wiki_? I think that would disassociate it from you.

Comment: @DanielDarabos No, it won't

Comment: Downvoting another answer shouldn't be the defacto solution to this scenario. Downvoting is for when a solution is incorrect. The quality of solutions (provided they are valid) should be determined by the most votes up. Otherwise it implies every answer you upvote, you should also downvote all other answers.

Comment: Ahem...[If _she_ happens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266351/my-accepted-answer-getting-downvoted-because-of-a-better-one-could-we-delete-m#comment65171_266355)... Good to know that answer is finally deleted.