# Why do we have the disciplined badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

To get the [disciplined badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined), you have to delete your own post that has a score of 3 or higher.

People upvote a post when it is good, right? So if it is good, why would the community want it deleted? They wouldn't, right? Yet you get a badge if you do, which might encourage some people to delete their own posts with +3 score, which may end up having gotten much higher over time and been a valuable post for the community.

Comment: An answer can "look good", get upvoted, but still be wrong. If you come to know that it is wrong, you delete it. I've been on the positive end of this, where my two-vote answer was dwarfed by a six-vote answer which got two more, even after the author marked it as incorrect(!). Author deleted the answer, got a badge.

Comment: Gamification (is also part of every badge here and for some more than for others.)

Comment: I saw wrong accepted answers with +100s upvotes. An upvote is a measure of popularity, not correctness.

Comment: Does anyone else find it ironic that this post has ended up with answers that were a perfect example of why the reward exists?

Comment: I feel like the explanation of why this badge exists should be placed on the "Badges" page. It makes perfect sense now that I've read the answers here, but I have wondered why it exists ever since I first saw that it existed.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Because your post doesn't add anything better than another answer, and the other answer includes everything that your post did, plus more.

For example, your post could just contain the correct working code, whereas another post would contain that, as well as a detailed explanation. Thus, you might as well just delete your answer.

Comment: I am not sure whether it really makes sense given that the community found your post useful ... so why destroy useful information?

Comment: @lpapp The fact that an answer alone is useful doesn't contradict that because of the other one it is also redundant.

Comment: @BartoszKP: how do you know for _sure_ that it is redundant? You may think it is, but the community may have upvoted it because they disagree with that! Why not just leave it with the community to decide whether it is truly dreadful that deserves deletion indicating that via giving many downvotes? Furthermore, I prefer short and concise answers compared to bloatware, so why not remove the bloatware instead? Can you see my point that you should not delete useful content judged so by your community behind?

Comment: @lpapp But you shouldn't downvote an answer just because *currently* it looks redundant. And of course you have a point there: different types of explanations work well for different people. But sometimes the case is as clear as lostsock presents in this answer: one answer is a strict subset of another one, and the other one is not some type of an overkill you mention. So of course I can't always know for sure, but sometimes I do.

Comment: @BartoszKP: I still do not get how you can be _really_ sure how different people like the information presented. It is personal taste. Like I said, I do not need a full blown answer if all I need is the short explanation. Everything else is useless bloat to me. As for your former point, I do think that it is better to downvote bloatware even if it contains everything that I needed, because it also contains much more, decreasing the signal/noise ratio. Therefore, I would just leave it with the community; they can decide to downvote it to oblivion over time, upvote it heavily or leave it as is.

Comment: @lpapp Lol, really, you consider one sentence of additional explanation as "bloatware"? Because I've explicitly stated that I'm not referring to answers with additional 10 paragraphs of text: "not some type of an overkill you mention". I'm talking about such simple and small additions, and downvoting posts because of that is harmful. Note that code-only answers are often considered Low Quality. This also excludes problems with "personal taste", because  only one additional sentence doesn't make significant difference in this matter. The discussion is about *existence* of such scenarios.

Comment: @BartoszKP: I am not sure what is "LOL" about my honest opinion, but yes,  I consider anything bloatware that does not give any additional value to what I need. Let us rename bloatware to superfluous noise if you like. I hope you get the point among the name games.

Comment: @lpapp Well, it means that I find your opinion, let's say, extraordinary. I think we're unlikely to find any common ground here, at least not without lengthy and boring discussion ;) So, I'll stop here, cheers :)

Comment: @lpapp: you asked the wrong question. The author of an answer can’t be perfectly sure that his answer is redundant or has other flaws that deserve deleting it. The point is, if the author decides to delete his own *upvoted* answer we can assume (s)he thought twice about it already. That’s more than we can assume about someone deleting his downvoted answer. It’s rather unlikely that people will abuse that to exchange 30+ rep points for a bronze badge.

Comment: @Holger: I will use my TU privileges to vote for undeletion if I see any such cases like that, I am afraid. All the reason is said above, already, but just for a friendly reminder: the community deemed the post useful, so let us not punish the community by removing useful content. PS.: 30+ rep is extremely low-price for a badge.

Answer (score 78):

Consider this scenario.

You answer a question with what you believe to be a correct answer, it gets upvoted because others think the same. You then realise, perhaps some time later, that the method will cause problems with another part of the user's code but you're not sure what the new correct answer should be, or another user has posted an answer that avoids the problems that yours will cause.

In this case you should delete the answer; and we have a badge for that.

Also, it's the antipode of the [Peer Pressure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge.

---

One person asked, so I should explain that *antipode* is broadly equivalent to *opposite*, but antipode is more appropriate as it indicates the two subjects are mutually exclusive (ie, one can exist without the other).

Comment: This is most likely the motivation. But oddly enough, you can't delete an accepted answer, and exactly the same scenario could apply to those.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but this very recent discussion suggested that you can't: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272849/please-allow-me-to-delete-my-own-accepted-answer.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Interesting. I always assumed you could since (a) the delete option was clickable, and (b) if you did click it the confirm warning dialogue came up.

Comment: Ha, just had to comment on the votes on this answer. I had 57 straight upvotes, and just got one downvote. I don't think that person was in tune with the rest of the community!

Comment: @worldofjr: you _cannot_ delete an accepted answer without moderator involvement.

Answer (score 36):

I earned the badge like this:

- OP asks slightly unclear question. I answer it to the best of my ability.
- The community upvotes my answer.
- The OP clarifies the question in comments or edits, revealing an error in my interpretation and making my answer obsolete.
- I delete my answer, as it is no longer helpful in any way.

I imagine this happens quite a bit.

Comment: Yeah, because people unnecessarily rush to answer unclear questions ([FGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)).

Comment: @BartoszKP Yep... I've definitely been guilty of that in the past.

Comment: Actually, if the question is clear, and the OP changes it, you should just revert the question edit and encourage the OP to submit a new question. This is a very poor way of losing a potentially valid question as well as an answer based on some "obsolete" reason.

Answer (score 7):

Some answers also become obsolete over time for a variety of reasons. Sure your answer could be updated with more recent information, however this might mean a complete rewrite of the answer, which might not be appropriate. And if there is already another answer that provides a more generic solution that is more resilient to change, or already has the updated information, then it might be best to just clean up your answer to prevent clutter and confusion.

Comment: I upvoted this to 3... will you dare delete it?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: outlfak did not. :(

Comment: Admittedly, I was tempted. My cold icy hands began to reach out for that Disciplined badge.... But alas, as my answer is specifically about the scenario where an answer becomes obsolete over time, I figured it would be best to wait until the day comes when this answer's usefulness itself vanishes into oblivion.

Comment: @ouflak: So, when the badge is no longer offered? Or when answers no longer become obsolete? :P