# Rewording of the disciplined badge?

Tags: discussion, tags

I originally came here to ask what's the point of the disciplined badge, but following [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274412/why-do-we-have-the-disciplined-badge) question, should the badge be reworded to be more specific?

As it stands, to get the badge it looks like you should just delete a well-received question of yours. It doesn't mention anything about a better answer existing elsewhere, or the answer being incorrect etc.

So maybe the description should justify at least one possible reason why you'd want to delete it?

Wouldn't you lose the points gained from the upvotes and accepting an answer? So, at least some justification should be offered?

Comment: The description of the badge usually just includes the exact criteria to win it. Like how "Tumbleweed" is a consolation prize, but that's not mentioned in the badge description.

Comment: @approxiblue I agree, but in this case, someone executing the action needed for this badge is actually harming the community if done incorrectly.

Comment: Why rewording? disciplined refers to harming your ego for the greater good. If your answer is a duplicate, then why keep it ?

Comment: @FabienBondi Because the question that's deleted by a user to get the badge may not be a duplicate as the badge description gives no hint towards that idea

Comment: Maybe change to: "just delete and undelete a well received answer to win a free badge" :D  No further explanations are needed, since free badges are the main reason!

Comment: Really? You keep the badge even if you undelete it?

Comment: @user3791372 I see your point. Then you may suggest a rewording ? Or maybe if there are several cases, it should be different badges. I've already seen questions tagged as duplicates by op but not answers though.

Comment: @user3791372 I agree. Maybe it's meant to be a gracious sort of thing where you realise your well-received answer is in fact completely invalid or raises security/bad practice concerns. Or you're simply giving way to a superior answer.

Comment: Even the concept of deleting an answer that is outdated doesn't fit well with me because of people working with different versions of libraries / software. A "better" answer is subjective and someone may find a 200 word answer better than a short answer with some code, whilst another may disagree and find the code answer better. So, could the badge just be seen as something esotoric?

Comment: I got it when I deleted my answer, because someone else posted the same while I was writing it.