# Disciplined badge - delete question or answer required?

Tags: discussion

The [Disciplined badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732) requires you to delete own post with score of 3 or higher, but it does not say whether "post" is a question or an answer.

Indeed there seems to be much confusion.

This related question with a good score...

*[Rewording of the disciplined badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307253/rewording-of-the-disciplined-badge)*

states ...

> to get the badge it looks like you should just delete a well-received
>   question

But the comments in that question state ...

> just delete and undelete a well received answer to win a free badge

so I remain confused as to whether I need to delete a well-received question or answer.

I feel this should be reworded to clarify the meaning better or that some 'additional information' should be available giving a more detailed description of how to achieve this badge.

What say ye meta?

Comment: "post" is "post", which is either a question or an answer, yes. either works for getting the badge, as it does for the badges opposite (peer pressure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The badge description has never once specifically said the post had to be either a question or an answer. The post you link to simply uses a question as an example. It does not imply that the badge is only awarded for deleting a question and not an answer. I don't know why the comments are going on about an answer.

Since a "post" is either a question or an answer, and the badge is awarded when deleting either kind of post, it is sufficient to say "post" in the badge description.

The reason badge descriptions are short and to the point is for you to discover how to attain them yourself. Otherwise there isn't much of a point to them — if they contained step-by-step instructions they might as well be help articles instead.