# Am I supposed to maintain my past answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, old-answers

I've been on Stack Overflow since 2009, and on Super User since it started.
I have over 500 answers combined.

Every once in a while, I get downvoted by a random passersby for standards that appeared long time after my answer (such as "provide more than a link", "don't quote an article", call it Stack Overflow and not StackOverflow" etc.)

I'm not even talking about answers that were true at 2011, but the technology shifted and now provides better answers.

My question is: am I supposed to constantly maintain my past answers? The standards can shift, and shift again. Am I doomed to revisit all my past answers, or just live with the fact people don't see the date next to an answer.

Comment: It's not _required_ to maintain your past posts, but if you have time and decide to go fix some old ones up, it's certainly a good idea. It's entirely impractical to expect someone with a large amount of answers to constantly go around them and revisit them for various issues that were less of an issue in the early years of SO. I would personally suggest (from a logical stand-point, I've yet to hit this issue myself anywhere) that you don't worry about them unless you receive a comment/dv on the answers. Then you could go and clean it up because that answer may need fixing.

Comment: You should 1) not have answers that are just links, so convert those to comments and delete the answer, or make the answer standalone 2) uh, properly quote articles? Not sure what that means and 3) ignore comments that don't mean anything.  Like this one.

Comment: Regarding converting link-only-answers to comments (or to edits on better answers): You won't even loose any rep, as they are presumably old enough the points are already permanent. And if the answer is actually good enough by your own standards or things cannot be made better with acceptable effort, just ignore both votes and comments.

Comment: I definitely only return to old answers if someone provides feedback on them. I have way too many answers to handle it any other way.

Comment: Whether you want to proactively look through your answers and update them over time is up to you.  If someone indicates that an answer is low quality now (even if it was once okay) you can either fix it in response to that comment, delete it if it's of no value and not worth fixing, or live with the feedback (presumably a downvote) that the post has problems and ignore it.

Comment: To echo what Servy said: I get downvotes occasionally on links that have become dead since I posted them. While it may technically be unfair to penalize me for something I didn't break, it's really a sign that the system works. I can choose to either update the link, delete the answer, or leave it be and risk further downvotes. There's no "right" path to take.

Comment: Stealing a comment from [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272849/please-allow-me-to-delete-my-own-accepted-answer#comment101752_272849) Posting an answer at SO can be a lot like teen-age sex. Ten minutes of fun and then you'll have to support it for the rest of your life.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers. I guess I should just go on the Stack Overflow online store, buy a tougher skin, and start ignoring down votes. To quote the known JavaScript guru Taylor Swift "Haters gonna hate" :)

Comment: .... or, if you absolutely need to disassociate yourself from an answer, make it a community wiki, and then almost anyone can improve it, and down-votes and up-votes won't affect you.