# Which priority is higher: serving individual users or the community?

Tags: discussion, meta

I read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306913/what-is-a-solution-to-the-stack-overflow-underdog-effect?cb=1) about underdog answers, and it brought up the following question:

Is stackoverflow primarily here to serve individual users and help them solve their problems, and then let the community see those solutions in case they have a similar problem? Or is it here to serve the community through the questions asked by individual users?

Right now it seems that stackoverflow is set to serve the individual user within the first few responses, but after the user has been helped, the goal is then to help the community (since the user has already had their question answered). Is this correct?

Comment: The goal is NEVER to help one user. It's really for the community. I don't get why you have the impression it starts one way then shifts, but the point of view "should help JUST the OP" is never the one Stack wants to have

Comment: Probably because of the arbitrary restrictions and bonuses acceptance places upon an answer and the fact that questions are considered answered when they have an accepted answer.

Comment: @BoltClock fair enough, but questions are also answered for upvoted answers, regardless of acceptance. To me, the checkmark just means "count the answer with an extra 1 in terms of votes"... but that may just be me. I agree the "votes" sorting could change that point of view since it throws accepted up top.

Comment: This question has bothered me for a while. Basically, the goal is to help the community AND the op, but only the op gets to decide which answer answers the question. You could say, then, why not just remove acceptance and just have upvotes? but then comes the issue of... How then do we distinguish between answered questions and questions with answers that are crap or don't answer the question. It seems more often than not that if a question has an accepted answer, it's a good answer.

Comment: @Patrice the best way to help the community is to help a single user. It's kind of like capitalism, where everyone is expected to work for their own benefit but the greater good becomes an emergent property (at least in theory).

Comment: @MarkRansom not at all. Helping a single user boils down to "answer every single question, regardless of likeliness of being looked up in the future". Answering a "please debug this" question is helping the user, but not the community. You need to look at questions with the inherent value for the community BEFORE deciding if you answer or not

Comment: @Patrice when an asker abandons their question answering it won't help the asker, so answering *all* questions certainly isn't the answer.  (sometimes it's necessary to teach the asker how to ask a question in order to even help them)  Note: Educating individuals also builds a stronger community.

Comment: @ebyrob I'm 100% with you here. In an ideal world, we would have time to do that and educate everyone. The reality of stack isn't that anymore. With the time constraints of life, and the number of new questions and users daily, educating everyone can't be done. It's unfortunate, but yeah...

Comment: @Patrice so if the goal is to help the community, why is the "accepted" answer posted above the more highly upvoted answers?

Comment: @ProQ that is actually a feature a LOT of people (me included) would like changed, exactly because it conveys that feeling

Comment: @Patrice how do people go about changing something like that?