# Pinging users to accept an answer / a different answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Possibly related: [Can moderators make an answer accepted to close the post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262672/can-moderators-make-an-answer-accepted-to-close-the-post)

Sometimes I see posts where the post below the accepted answer has gotten more upvotes than the accepted one, and people often comment (either on the question or the accepted answer) something along the lines of "The answer below this should be accepted" or "See the answer below this" or "See so-and-so's answer". Often, the person who wrote the accepted answer will edit their answer to refer to or point out the "better" answer.

Would it be worthwhile to implement a way to ping users when the community thinks that a different answer should be the accepted one? This would allow the person providing the better answer to receive "official"/stat-tracked recognition, and would provide faster access to a better answer.

This feature could also be used if a user hasn't accepted an answer on one of their questions, for example; but that might not be desirable, as discussed in the comments in the question linked to above.

Comment: Yes, the ping is a comment. And if the user isn't active, they won't see the comment (or your proposed ping) anyway.

Comment: Related: [What is a solution to the Stack Overflow “underdog effect”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306913/what-is-a-solution-to-the-stack-overflow-underdog-effect)

Answer (score 7):

## Conclusion: no.

Reasons:

- The comment implements this functionality, as active users will see the comment, while inactive users wouldn't see the ping anyway. (Trobbins)
- Not a problem. (Tiny Giant)
- Accepted answers make note of what worked for the question authors themselves (Zizouz212)

See [What is a solution to the Stack Overflow "underdog effect"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306913/what-is-a-solution-to-the-stack-overflow-underdog-effect) (Trobbins)

Comment: I wish more users did this with their Meta posts. Good on you.