# Trying to delete my incorrect accepted answer

Tags: support, answers, flags

I have made an answer last month for which I have determined it is not correct.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38478030/4082723

Therefore I tried to delete. Of course this was not possible as the system wouldn't allow it, with a red box: *You cannot delete this accepted answer*

Therefore I flagged the answer for deletion 5 days ago. At the same time I edited the answer with a striketrough font, leaving the text itself intact, to warn possible readers.

Since no-one addressed my flag for 5 days, I decided, 6 hours ago, to take more drastic action and remove the text in the answer and replace it with: *Delete this answer please*, hoping it would get attention.

Today I got an anonymous response for the flag: *declined - That's not how this works. Please do not deface your answer. You can edit it to make it correct, or you can delete it yourself. But don't destroy the content.*

I choose to delete the incorrect answer, system wouldn't let me, and the anonymous response told me to delete the answer. I don't see how this is logical.

Please delete the incorrect answer.

Comment: I'd say the key is _"You can edit it to make it correct"_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ One should always have the option to delete it, and apparently we do: *You can edit it to make it correct, or you can delete it yourself.* In addition, knowing that something is not correct does not imply that a correct solution is known. How can I correct something for which I don't know the correct answer.

Comment: When you flagged your post, what exactly did you say?  Did you mention that it was an accepted answer that you couldn't delete on your own?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I said: *Please delete this answer. I have realized it is not correct.* But a person handling these flags, presumably a person familiar with the site, a moderator, `should` be aware of the fact that accepted answers cannot be deleted by its owners.

Comment: Related feature request: [Please allow me to delete my own accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272849/please-allow-me-to-delete-my-own-accepted-answer)

Comment: @2501 that was your mistake. You need to be very specific why you want the moderator to take such action. They get stupid flags frequently and have a lot to handle so they cannot possibly take too much extra time to research the details. What you should have said is something along the lines of "My answer is incorrect and I'd like to delete it, but I am unable to do so because it is currently accepted and I cannot delete it on my own".  I can't promise they would have deleted it, but when you spell out all of the facts, it makes it easier for them and more likely they act as you want them too.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't agree. My reasoning is in my above comment.

Comment: @2501 you are assuming that in the flag review tool for the moderators, they can see all of those details.  I've never seen it myself, but my understanding is it doesn't contain details like that.  That is why mods want you to be specific in your custom flags to explain what you want them to do and why you can't do it yourself.

Comment: Revising an accepted and upvoted answer to say (as I understand it) the opposite is, quite reasonably, frowned upon. If do have a new answer, post it as such and explain why the accepted answer does not work. Then the voting system should do its work (which is independent from the "Accepted" status - at least, we all hope it does).

Comment: @RadLexus we want to fix incorrect content before anything else. Until users have the ability to delete their own incorrect accepted answers, there are no easy solutions except editing the answer

Comment: Regardless of your wish of the answer being removed: Do not do edits like these to your post ever: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38478030/revisions (revisions 6/7)!

Comment: @fabian You're ignoring the context. That edit was justified.

Comment: If the answer was accepted, then it means that it addressed askers's problem. You can add a disclaimer at the beginning of the answer letting people know the answer is incorrect, but leaving it intact as it solved asker's  problem.

Comment: @psubsee2003: sure - and I am all for that (although I hope you mean "downvoting", not *fixing* someone else's answer). However, it's the "accepted" mark that makes this a special case! As Cristik says, in its incorrect form it still helped the OP - we don't know why, though. Maybe we should go as far as adding a comment and asking to *retract* that checkmark.

Comment: @RadLexus OP got incorrect information and has not been on SO since.

Comment: @2501: well what did you expect :) He got an answer, submitted it to his teacher / boss / job interviewer, and was told it was wrong... What do you think about my suggestion to post a second answer, refuting the former? You can ask for the other one to be disassociated from your account.

Comment: @RadLexus well, I would worry since it had to do something with "Tor source code"... what if OP enabled the asker to make software that protects the privacy of several users vulnerable?

Comment: @Braiam: the more painful it is, then, that OP did not notice 2501's answer was not correct :P (N/m my previous comment; sorry.)

Comment: @2501: That edit was not justified regardless of the context. You don't get to decide how long a flag has to remain pending before you take matters into your own hands.

Comment: @2501 Apparently the mod tools on StackOverflow are (1.) an awful user experience for said moderator and (2.) never getting fixed, so unfortunately you have to do mental gymnastics every time you raise a flag. While I agree with you in principle, the realistic answer is that you have to explain custom flags like someone is going to be looking at your post [through a straw](http://goodomenslexicon.org/articles/agnes-nutter/) and not seeing any context.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: You know, this has got me wondering: for all that we talk about how removing or striking out content is vandalism, how is completely changing a wrong answer into a different (if correct) one any different? Either way you're still completely removing or striking out the original content in favor of an entirely different answer altogether. Why is one OK but not the other, even in the specific context of holding accepted answers hostage? (I know [you were not the first to suggest this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272988).)

Comment: @Cristik SO is supposed to be a knowledge repository not a help desk. The fact that it solved one person's problem who may never be back is far less important than being _correct_, and that should not be a metric for determining what content gets left in what state.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist then the question shouldn't have been answered in the first place. But the question in discussion doesn't seem to be off-topic.

Comment: @Cristik the fact that the questioner believed that an incorrect answer had solved their problem doesn't mean that the question shouldn't have been answered in the first place. A correct answer could of course be generally useful.

Comment: @MartinSmith this is not what I said (or I wanted to say). My point was that if a question doesn't deserve an answer, it shouldn't be answered. Asker's behaviour is not what it matters here, is the answerer's one.

Comment: @fabian that's a pretty strong comment - the guy/girl has a right to edit their answer as much as they want. It really is not up to anyone else. That's why they give us the "edit" button.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Of course you should be allowed to edit your post and clarifying a error in the answer is a good reason to do this. However simply changing the post to *Please delete this answer!* or by using strikethrough on the whole post is IMHO a no-go. Other people saw this post and voted on it and such a edit completely changes the meaning of the post and people shouldn't have to read through the comments section to find out the reason. Strikethrough + an explanation why it was wrong would be OK though.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I declined that flag because you were defacing the content. Editing to improve it or add a disclaimer is fine. Defacing it is not. I did not see any indication that you tried to fix the answer or that you were unable to delete it.

I've deleted it now. In the future, please explain what you want (deletion), why you need moderator attention (the system won't allow it), and *why the post should be deleted at all* (*why* is it wrong?). Please do not just destroy it.

Comment: I did two of the three thing you listed. The second one should be obvious to a moderator, an accepted answer cannot be deleted.

Comment: I did not deface it, it was marked for 5 days with a striketrough while the flag was ignored. I wonder if the flag would have been addressed at all had I not actually modified the text.

Comment: @2501 Actually, you did one. You didn't say *why* it was wrong, and striking out all the content is still defacement.

Comment: @2501: Many users choose to do the wrong thing on purpose in order to get our attention. But that's only going to get you a *different* kind of attention... had you waited patiently for a moderator to delete your answer instead of taking matters into your own hands, you probably would have avoided all this hoo-ha.

Comment: Hilariously, [Jeff Atwood of all people was the first to suggest striking out an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances/60107#60107). And look how *that* turned out...

Comment: The flag functionality on this site is broken if the people viewing the flags don't make some effort before declining them imho

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier We do make effort. But we also get 2,000 flags per day, many of which are complete garbage. We take time to check things out, but don't have time to evaluate whether an answer that both OP and the answerer/flagger originally thought was right is really wrong somehow. Put differently, the flagger also needs to put in some effort to explain the problem.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier It's broken but not because of lack of mod effort. Rather, because it _requires_ so much mod effort to overcome the apparent lack of information and context they are presented with by their tools. This, in turn, requires that flaggers be experts in the secret formula for a successful flag, which is different for each one and not at all obvious unless you're on Meta every day. The worst offender is of course the [NAA flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308441/using-naa-on-jokes-that-make-no-attempt-to-answer-the-question).

Comment: @Ed, Two-Bit. I hear you guys both (and no, I have not, nor will I, put up my hand to mod the flags). But I do align myself more with Two-Bit's response where he acknowledges that "flaggers be experts in the secret formula" which is very unfortunate. I have often been bitten with invalid flagging for basic junk on the site, hence my opinion that this system "is broken"

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Part of the problem is that people are applying a different standard when raising flags than when writing questions and answers. The basics of writing posts apply: make the flag clear, self-contained as much as possible, and complete, including a MCVE if, say, talking about serial abuse of some sort. In other words, the "secret formula" is to raise flags that are clear and make sense without a ton of investigation. That said, the mod tools can always use improvement, and the SE team is great about working to improve them and meet our needs as problems arise.

Comment: @EdCottrell I totally disagree. As [this recent Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333722/2588818) shows the problems with flagging are certainly not limited to flags being raised in ways that are not "clear and make sense without a ton of investigation." The concensus on NAA has been repeatedly described as "does not even remotely attempt to answer _any_ question whatsoever" which is more in line with what I was describing as only obvious to those of us on Meta every day, and not at all obvious (from the perspective of a new flagger just using the UI normally).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I didn't say the problems are "limited" to that. I said, "*Part* of the problem...." Also, in case it's not clear, I'm not really talking about NAA flags. There's a lot of confusion around them, but the flag itself has a defined meaning and purpose. I'm talking about *custom* flags. We get a ton of them, and many make no sense at all. Maybe 50% are really clear. Only a few per day are (1) clear, (2) self-contained, *and* (3) actually helpful. And, of course, some of the standard flags get abused a lot. Half of the "spam" flags we see really just mean "I don't like this post."

Comment: @EdCottrell Ahh, we're just on slightly different subjects then. I wasn't only talking about custom flags. And I do want to reiterate that I have the utmost sympathy for the amount of crap flags you undoubtedly see in a day's time. I can only imagine.

Answer (score 10):

I think you did everything you could to delete out-of-date useless information from Stack Overflow, and I commend you for it. Stack Overflow has far too much out-of-date information, and there isn't a good system for cleaning it up, so efforts like yours are appreciated.